# Apache cant load Files of localhost, returning error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My server isnt loading direct links on its header of html pages.Where dev.pauloxavier.com is an alias for 127.0.0.1. Example:

```
http://dev.pauloxavier.com/certified/framework/assets/css/custom.css
http://dev.pauloxavier.com/certified/framework/assets/css/bootstrap.css
```

I cant access this file direct on the browser, either. Error 500 is returned.

On the log of errors i got:

```
[Mon May 11 12:26:28.724782 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 2864:tid 1828] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client 127.0.0.1:51598] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: E:/GitHub/certified/framework/assets/img/favicon.png, referer: http://dev.pauloxavier.com/certified/
```

My htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteBase /certified/
RewriteRule  ^user/([a-z]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/?$ index.php?to=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^import/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/?$ index.php?to=import&id_evento=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^evento/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/?$ index.php?to=evento&id_evento=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^inserir/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/?$ index.php?to=inserir&id_evento=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^remover/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/?$ index.php?to=remover&id_evento=$1&id_participante=$2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^envio/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/?$ index.php?to=envio&id_evento=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^certificado/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{1,100})/?$ index.php?to=certificado&evento=$1&particip=$2 [L]
```

My directory on apache is configured as:

```
<Directory "E:/GitHub/certified">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And using the alias:

```
ScriptAlias /certified/ "E:/GitHub/certified/"
```

What is most strange is: This version is working on my webserver, and used to work on my local, but i lost my hd, and had to reinstall everything from scratch. I really think that is a problem with apache, like a misconfig.

Thanks in advance!